# What to do if I know that I won't get enough sleep

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, manager

It is around 3am and I've been fruitlessly trying to fall asleep for almost three hours now. The ferry I take to the office departs at 0730. No matter what happens, there is no way I can make it and get enough sleep to be fully productive tomorrow.

From a work perspective, how should I address this situation? This happens once, sometimes twice a month. I'm not willing to take a day off because of things that are out of my control.

(Please focus on the professional aspect and not on fixing my sleeping issue, this is an independent ongoing investigation.)

Comment: If this question is not about fixing your sleeping issue, your 'What should I do' question is very vague; off-topic actually.

Comment: Your question sounds like you went to bed around midnight. If your ferry leaves at 7:30, it sounds like you would not have gotten much more than six hours of sleep anyway. Are you sure that this is enough for you? I agree that you may need to work on your sleep cycle.

Comment: Over 7 hours, which is enough. I wake up at 0715, the ferry is 100m from my place, and I eat the breakfast in the office.

Comment: "What should I do in this situation? "  Turn off the TV and/or Computer.

Comment: Find things that you can be productive at when tired.  Focus on these.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must not be a parent because parents with young children have to fight through this situation routinely.

In any event, the correct answer to your question is:

- Wake up at your regularly scheduled time to make your final decision.
- If indeed you won't be able to make it into the office today, then either send your boss an email or leave him/her a voicemail, explaining the situation. Honesty is the best policy.

  - Depending upon your specific circumstances, it will be necessary for you to either work from home or take a sick day.
- And if they have a sense of humor and they're younger than 45, include [this music video](http://youtu.be/lwPRNRJhjgg).

Long term, you will need to either fix this situation or learn to adapt and fight through it because absenteeism will diminish your reputation. If this happens more than a few times, people will regard you as someone who can't be depended upon.

Comment: Haha! You hit the nail on the head about how parents deal with this!  Especially the parent of an infant or toddler like myself.

Comment: @maple_shaft I'm really impressed that a toddler like yourself has 12k rep on Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: Upvoted, but not sure I agree with the assumption that Yan Domner must not be a parent---they could be a new parent who's just now starting to deal with sleep deprivation, someone whose kids are grown and who doesn't function as well on little sleep as they could when they were younger, etc.

Comment: Also, I think it would make the answer better to address the "I'm not willing to take a day off because of something out of my control." portion of the question.  It's a completely understandable preference, especially if you don't get paid sick leave or if sick and vacation are combined, but it's not really feasible.  Getting sick, having your car break down, or having a sick kid are beyond your control too, but they usually necessitate taking a day off.